# Store a custom serial number on a USB flash drive, immune to overwriting

Tags: usb-drive, storage, uuid

I'm working with massive amounts of USB flash memory.
I'd like to be able to track events regarding the USB drives.
Specifically: I perform `f3` tests, format the drives and write data to them.

I'm looking for a way to mark the drives digitally (for example with a UUID) so I can perform various actions with the drive while having the serial numbers intact. Hopefully also have other people use and format the drives, still allowing me to read the serial number off of them later.

I have tried using the serial number reported by the USB device, but I've soon have found out that the majority of the drives have no uniquely identifying information stored in them.

Hence - I have tired generating a UUID concatenated with it's own CRC sum so I can write that string to the drive and read it back, verifying if it was stored correctly.

Writing the serial number to the filesystem however means that once the drive is filled up the every copy of the serial number will be overwritten.

My latest idea is to partition the drive to leave 1 MB of unpartitioned empty space so I can store the serial number there.

This is going to have a marginal impact on a drive's usefullness but should allow me to somewhat reliably identify drives, as long as the drive will not be repartitioned.

Ideally each drive would have a UUID written to the Mass Storage driver chip and would report that - but I don't manufacture the drives.

I thought about generating the serial numbers a bit like this (Bash):

```
UUID=$(uuidgen)
CK=$(echo "$UUID" | cksum | cut -c -8)
SN="SN:$UUID:$CK;"
echo $SN
```

This generates a UUID, calculates a CRC sum of that UUID, leaves just 8 first characters of that sum (because the length can vary and we need a constant length to effectively search for the pattern later). Then it concatenates that with some markers that can be used to extract the number form a data stream and verify if it wasn't damaged.

Example serial numbers:

```
SN:7199e42e-465b-4baf-96b6-a109247d3f4b:39272476;
SN:aa795142-fa2e-4929-b93b-e991f95a74cd:40619286;
SN:43f93702-eda9-4089-9a81-d21172e051bf:37174302;
```

I can then verify the serial number integrity like this:

```
SN="SN:7199e42e-465b-4baf-96b6-a109247d3f4b:39272476;"
UUID=$(echo "$SN" | cut -d':' -f2)
CK=$(echo "$SN" | cut -d':' -f3 | cut -d';' -f1)
if [[ $(echo "$UUID" | cksum | cut -c -8) == $CK ]]; then
    echo "SN is fine"
else echo "SN is corrupted"; fi
```

I can also extract a serial number from a drive with `grep`:

```
cat /dev/sdX | grep -E "SN:.{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12}:.{8};" -o
```

Then I'd get a list of serial numbers, and evaluate them until I find one that has a matching checksum.

Because I work with potentially faulty drives I need to write the serial number in multiple copies so at least one copy will survive.

I wonder if there's a better approach to what I'm trying to do - without of course resorting to manufacturing my own flash memory,

**EDIT: UDEVADM**

I can try to get a unique identifier using various read-only information from the drive itself:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sdd | grep -e "ID_MODEL" -e "ID_SERIAL" -e "ID_VENDOR"
E: ID_MODEL=Flash_Disk
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Flash\x20Disk\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6387
E: ID_SERIAL=Generic_Flash_Disk_97C06F44-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=97C06F44
E: ID_VENDOR=Generic
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Generic\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=058f

$ udevadm info /dev/sdd | grep -e "ID_MODEL" -e "ID_SERIAL" -e "ID_VENDOR" | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
7b7f63b829b6301cdf35d71eed9bb707
```

I am almost certain however that I'll encounter a lot of drives that return identical values here - making this approach useless.

EDIT2:

I have accumulated nearly 1600 datapoints on this, and most drives seem to produce unique hashes, but I got still around 400 drives that returned identical hashes, so this method alone is not enough.

Comment: I would advice you to use the MD5 or the SHA1 hash algorithms to check the integrity of the UUID, as the CRC is not the best alternative to check the integrity of anything.

Comment: There are many possible ways to do this, but I would try one of these: store the UUID in the device using some obscure vendor commands and retrieve it using `lsusb` (see http://www.usbdev.ru/ for vendor-specific tools), keep storing the UUID in some reserved space at a known location on the memory or use a secondary hidden LUN to store metadata (again, this requires to investigate the vendor commands). If you can find some sort of unique identifier already set by the vendor, as @imbuedHope suggests, I advice you to use it.

Comment: Why do you need to complicate that so much? Instead of leaving unpartitioned space, which will be inevitably used by the controller to remap bad blocks, create a small partition and store your information there, separately from the rest of data.

Comment: @ajeh - wouldn't creating a separate partition make that partition auto-mount on Windows systems, rising confusion and problems? Or can I make it hidden somehow?

Comment: If you create a small partition, will you be able to avoid overwriting it with your tests? In that case it might work. You can select a file system, for example FAT32, that Windows can read (and Windows is happy with it), or a file system that Windows cannot read, for example `ext4`, and Windows will suggest that you format it, but you should be able to resist that. Or will these USB flash drives be distributed to other people, who may not resist the prompt to format?

Comment: @unfa I am very hesitant to enter into debates about anyone getting confused, as the whole thing is highly subjective. But your question is Linux related, so if your partition was formatted as any Linux native FS types, Windows would not attempt mounting it.

Comment: @sudodus - the drives would be distributed to other people (clients basically), so anything strange like two partitions detected by Windows or prompts to format the drive are unacceptable - that's why I wanted to try a small unpartitioned space so it doesn't result in any annoyances to the end users. I do my tests with `f3` and it works on the file level, so it won't write or read beyond provided partitions.

Comment: @ajehw - I am not sure if these drives are smart enough to remap bad blocks. Otherwise `f3` tests would probably not give me any errors until the drives are absolutely wrecked, and I often find a few kB of bad capacity on them. If so - is there a way to make Windows ignore a partition entirely?

Comment: @unfa, 1. I don't know Windows well enough to know if there is a way to make Windows ignore a partition entirely; 2. *If you do **not** intend to make these drives boot in BIOS mode*, you could use the drive space between the first 512 bytes and the beginnning of the second mibibyte (where grub-pc will put data for the bootloader, so most of the first mibibyte. This part of the drive will not be partitioned by linux tools (for example by gparted), and you can write things to it for example near the end of it using `dd`. This could be a good and safe place for your special identification data.

Comment: @unfa, I don't know how much of that drive space, that is actually used by grub (and maybe some other bootloader, or raid configuration or whatever), but maybe the last part of this first mibibyte will not be touched. In this case it should work even if you create USB boot drives for BIOS mode. You can test it; it should be easy to check if your identification will be overwritten by grub.

Comment: @unfa, I suggest that you try to use the last part of this first mibibyte for your own ID, and check if for example grub (in BIOS mode) will touch it or not. -- I checked it quickly, and grub version 2.02-beta2 (in Ubuntu 16.04) uses only about 5% or that first mibibyte, so you can use the 'last kibibyte of the first mibibyte' for your checksum and have a wide margin :-) But stay away from tools that wipe the first mibibyte when you do those tests ;-)

Comment: @unfa, I tested `gparted`: Both when creating an MSDOS partition table and a GPT, and after those operations using 'the whole drive' to create a partition with a file system, the last kibibyte of the first mibibyte is untouched, so your own ID will be preserved (if you put it there).

Comment: @sudodus - that sounds interesting. I have done a tests where I've written a drive full with `dd` and after formatting and writing the filesystem full - everything was overwriitten. However - I used `mkntfs -QF` and made the filesystem on the bare drive, without a partition. Maybe that's why it didn't work as you've experienced it. I'll research this. Thanks!

Comment: Update: for now I've implemented it by partitioning the drives to leave unused last 10 kB on the drive - I write the ID repeated there, along with the checksums, then I read through all of them until I find one that's matching it's checksum - it works, it's fast, it's rugged against bitrot, and also it can survive formatting the drive in Windows, and doens't cause any confusion both during testing and regular use.

Comment: @ajeh  I don't think leaving an unpartitioned space will result in the memory controller using that for remapping bad blocks. First: USB flash memory controllers are usually configured once at the factory, and the don't remap anything after that (unlike hard drives). Second: even if they did, it'd not affect any user-accessible part of the drive - I don't think the memory controllers know or care about partitions. If you have a "multi-partition" drive (for example with one partition being read-only) it's actually done by exposing 2 separate mass storage devices. At least that's my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The `ID_SERIAL` of the device usually does the trick for verifying the identity of a device.

It is persistent across formatting because it's a property of the device itself; however, afaik, you cannot change it due to the same reason.

You can get it by running: `udevadm info /dev/sdX | grep ID_SERIAL=`

Comment: I'll have to check, but I think  that many devices I work with return identical values.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent device naming (a name that is the same across diferent mount points) is an elusive goal. There are several UUIDs created in several containers (filesystem, mount point, etc) as [described in detail here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming).

An UUID (well, actually a World Wide Identifier (WWID)) [given by the hardware of the USB device](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/persistent_naming) connected may be given in:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

But understand that not all devices support such numbering.

Comment: I deal with many chineese USB flash memory modules and many report the vendor as "Generic" and serial as "1234". There are so called "MP tools" (Mass Production) that are vendor-specific programs used to write the metadata to the flash memory controller chip at the manufacturing facility. I wish they assigned UUIDs to all the drives, it'd make things much easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some flash storage is not uniquely identifiable after a format and the best you can do is set custom partition UUIDs or upgrade to better storage.

https://superuser.com/questions/1247972/change-uuid-of-vfat-partition